# Replacing the standard exception/error form in .net

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I was thinking, is it possible to "override" or maybe replace the standard winforms .net Exception form??

I am talking about this dude:

[image]

Is it possible, during the scope of the hole program, to override this windows? I mean automatically, without having to perform try/catch.

Answer (score 2):

You can handle [System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx) event to show your custom message.

Answer (score 2):

You should handle both the following events:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException 
Application.ThreadException
```

In those handlers you could display a custom form that you made.

Answer (score 2):

This is the ThreadExceptionDialog class, it derives from the Form class.  Deriving from it to alter the dialog is a lost cause, you can't easily get to the embedded controls.  You can create your own Form derived class to make your own dialog just as well, just give it a constructor that takes an Exception argument.  Implement an event handler for Application.ThreadException to display it.

Do note the fundamental flaw in the dialog.  It expects the user to make the right choice when she needs to click a button to dismiss the dialog.  With, in general, fairly obscure information about what exactly went wrong.  It means something to you, rarely anything more than 'oh crap' to the user.  Clicking the Continue button is not typically the right thing to do.

To avoid the user having to make such a difficult choice, call Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode() in your Main() method, passing ThrowException so that the event is never raised.  Every unhandled exception now goes through AppDomain.UnhandledException.  Including the ones that were raised in a worker thread, exceptions that *don't* produce the dialog.  Write an event handler for it and display and/or log the value of e.ExceptionObject.ToString().  It is up to you to sort out a way to get that info to your desk, or the user's IT staff, so you can improve your product and they can get their machines stable.

Answer (score 0):

In webforms, you can handle Application_Error in global.asax. But it seems like you're talking about winforms. In that case:
try adding the following code into your main starter method:

```
Application.ThreadException += new System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventHandler(ExceptionHandler.OnThreadException);
```

And define the ExceptionHandler class as follows:

```
/// <summary>
/// Main thread error handler.
/// </summary>
public sealed class ExceptionHandler
{
    private ExceptionHandler()
    {}

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles an exception on the main thread.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="t"></param>
    public static void OnThreadException(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs t) 
    {
        DialogResult result = DialogResult.Cancel;
        try
        {
            result = ShowThreadExceptionDialog(t.Exception);
        }
        catch
        {
            try
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Fatal Error", "Application Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
            }
            finally
            {
                Application.Exit();
            }
        }

        // Exits the program when the user clicks Abort.
        if (result == DialogResult.Abort) 
            Application.Exit();
    }

    // Creates the error message and displays it.
    private static DialogResult ShowThreadExceptionDialog(Exception e) 
    {
        string errorMsg = "An error occurred please contact the adminstrator with the following information:\n\n";
        errorMsg = errorMsg + e.Message + "\n\nStack Trace:\n" + e.StackTrace;
        return MessageBox.Show(errorMsg, "Application Error", MessageBoxButtons.AbortRetryIgnore, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
    }
}
```

taken from:  http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/2/27469/any-method-for-handling-error-globally-in-c.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/unhandledexceptions.aspx) link.

From the page:

**Introduction**

One of the things that impressed me when I first started learning .NET was its enhanced exception-handling functionality. By this I mean such features as easy access to the type of exception thrown, full stack trace and inner exceptions. This makes it easy to still get full information in those places where you just catch a top-level System.Exception. I find this convenient since, if you don't need to take specific action on a particular type of exception, it is tedious to have successive catch handlers for each type of exception that may be thrown. In any case, even if you do catch specific exceptions you usually also need to catch System.Exception just to cover yourself and prevent program crashes. Thus I find that I end up catching System.Exception all over the place in my code. A typical scenario is that in Windows Forms and ASP.NET Web Forms applications, all of my non-trivial event handlers end up containing try-catch System.Exception blocks.

The trouble is that this does still clutter up the code somewhat and doesn't really seem quite right. Is there a better way?